# how to call existing navigationcontroller in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 items in my storyboard. 1. viewController (A) connected to 2. Navigation controller and 3. viewController (B) is NOT connected to anything 
All 3 items have restoration identifiers set in the storyboard.

viewController (B) is the initial view controller.
I am trying in B to get the navigation controller that A is attached to, but always returns nil:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewControllerA") as! ViewControllerA
print(vc.navigationController?) // always prints nil
```

why!?

**UPDATE#1**
I can't declare a UINavigationController like a view controller. I've tried setting navigationcontroller with the id of 'myNavigationController' as storyboardID:

When storyboard, I get this error

```
let navigationController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
print(self.navigationController!) // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I've also tried setting the id in restoration identifier, It bombed earlier at the instantiating line

@ColdLogic, see what hits I get when I search the entire project for that identifier:

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but you are actually instantiating the view controller which doesn't also instantiate it's parent navigation controller. You need to separately instantiate the nav controller then add the view controller as a child

Comment: Are you sure you have name ViewController A as `viewControllerA` in the storyboard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you never instantiated the navigation controller, you instantiated view controller A. You would want something like this if you want both the nav controller and the view controller to be setup like they are in the storyboard

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
let navigationController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourNavControllerIdentifier") as! UINavigationController
let vc = navigationController.topViewController as! ViewControllerA
```

Your code directly instantiates an object of type ViewControllerA. Which, unless you setup logic to do it, does not have a navigation controller by default.

Comment: I can't instantiate navigation controller like you said. See my update

Comment: Then the storyboard identifier isn't `myNavigationController`. Double check you are using the correct storyboard identifier to instantiate the navigation controller.

Comment: Sorry, didnt read your update closely enough. the `self.` is why its nil. try `println(navigationController)`. Where ever you are running this code doesnt have a `navigationController` object. But this `println` will print the one you just created from the storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

This Worked for me!

```
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeNavigationContoller") as! UINavigationController

    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    navigationController.pushViewController(messageVC, animated: true)

    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it! Worked to me!

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationController` identifier to access the `NavigationController` and ViewController A is already attached to it, so it will automatically get loaded to `NavigationController`

Comment: It sems that code can't find ids for navigationcontrollers. I've tried repeatedly. Check my updates.